# Solution for local application settings

Tags: c#, wpf, local-storage, outlook-addin

I am looking for a way to store local settings of my MS Outlook add-in WPF application.

I have been reading this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973902.aspx#persistappsettnet_creatingcustomclass (Persisting Application Settings in the .NET Framework) which describes how to persist local settings in a custom application settings class.  However, this article is from June 2002 and for Windows Forms application.

**I wonder if this is still a "good" way of doing it for my type of application?**

I have looked at couple of other options but they dont seem to be applicable to my application type.  Here are some:

- Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#Storing_app_data_in_the_app_data_stores).  However, this is for Windows Store Apps
- Application Settings ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx). However, this is not working for MS Outlook Add-Ins (as per "Limitation of Application Settings" section in the document).

Comment: Look at ConfigurationSection to make your own configuration items. You can save the configuration in a separate file rather than your app.config. Loading and saving comes "out of the box".

Comment: [Using Application Settngs and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You will have to add the network thing on top but that shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1° create a class that represents your runtime settings
2° use manual properties instead functions to manage validation like in:

```
public long DownloadPeriod
{
    get { return _DownloadPeriod; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 0) _DownloadPeriod = value;
        else throw new Exception("invalid value");
    }
}
private long _DownloadPeriod;
```

3° use the an XML file to store it locally 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part
4° create a function that can download the xml from the server and update the local setting according your own rules.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @AllanLeaon Thanks but xml file is not an option.  i dont want user tempering it.

Comment: than this should solve your user problem http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26085/File-Encryption-and-Decryption-in-C